# Ficus Elastica - yellow and red spots, please help!

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, ficus

I bought a *Ficus elastica* and noticed some strange spots! Could you please help identify the problem and offer some help? Thank you so much! Larger versions of the photo are on reddit [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/plantclinic/comments/lwankr/hi_everyone_does_this_ficus_look_unwell_ive_just/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share).

Thank you so much!

[image]